# How to use indices_boost in FOSElasticaBundle?

Tags: elasticsearch, foselasticabundle

I have this query that gets what I need, it is just an example, but will do it.

```
{
    "indices_boost": { 
        "customer": 3,
        "customer_contact": 2
    },
    "query": {
        "term" : { "all" : "google" } 
    }
}
```

Problem is that I want to use it in FOSElasticaBundle, and I don't know if that is even possible. I know that is is not 100% the same query, but I just need to add the "indices_boost" somewhere. As I have to use 2 indexes, the query is a bit more complex than usually is.

```
$queryObject = new \Elastica\Query\BoolQuery();
$tagsQuery = new \Elastica\Query\Terms();
$tagsQuery->setTerms('all', ['google']);
$queryObject->addShould($tagsQuery);

$repositoryManager = $this->get('fos_elastica.index_manager');
$search = $repositoryManager->getIndex('customer')->createSearch($queryObject, 20);
$search->addIndex('customer_contact');
$search->search($queryObject, 20)->getResults();
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally made it work.

I guess FOSelasticBundle is not ready yet for this option, but there is a way to add custom parameters into a query.

```
$query = new \Elastica\Query($queryObject);
$indicesBoost = [
    "customer" => 3,
    "customer_contact" => 2
];
$query->setParam("indices_boost", $indicesBoost);
```